# Fill table with json class data

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I have a table according to the :

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped tree-grid">
        <thead class="text-primary">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>level1
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th>level2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="x" class="tree-grid-row">
            <td style="width:85px" class="text-primary"></td>
            <td style="width:50px">
              <label>self</label>
              <br />
              <label>employee</label>
              <br />
              <label>chef</label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30px">
              <label type="text">1</label>
              <br />
              <label type="text">2</label>
              <br />
              <label type="text">3</label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30px">
              <label type="text">4</label>
              <br />
              <label type="text">5</label>
              <br />
              <label type="text">6</label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30px">
              <label type="text">7</label>
              <br />
              <label type="text">8</label>
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now i want json data set in tr `id="x"` with `ng-repeat and {{}}` for binding that every label value in html td tags set first field data json. sample :

```
[
  {
    "Weight": 25,
    "Goal": 26,

    "Name": "Jack  ",
    "Description": "2.5",
    "Area": "52%",
    "Population": "-",
  "DemographicId": 1,  
          "ParentId": null
  },
  {
    "Weight": 55,
    "Goal": 26,

    "Name": "Mojtaba  ",
    "Description": "2.5",
    "Area": "52%",
    "Population": "-",
  "DemographicId": 2,  
          "ParentId": 1
  },...]
```

Suppose i have 1000 to record data json. i want with `ng-repeat` and `{{}}` set label value first row every field json data into my table.
  my tr tag for each data record first line I want json to be fill.

Comment: may i know your expected output

Comment: Please help me :((

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ng-repeat to your code similar to this one:

```
<tr id="x" class="tree-grid-row" ng-repeat="data in myJsonData">
    <td>
        <label>{{data.Name}}</label>
        <br />
        <label>{{data.Description}}</label>
        <br />
        <label>{{data.Weight}}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>{{data.Goal}}</label>
    </td>
    .
    .
    .
</tr>
```

and so on..

Comment: If i set multi label in pro td tag, can you get me codes?

Comment: I will different value in pro label in a TD tag.

Comment: What is pro label? Try writing the code yourself first, then we can help you with the problems.

Comment: Pro different label in td tags fiil with data json.

Comment: I want use '  {{items[$index+1].id}} {{items[$index+1].name}} ...' .
For each label in a tag td, i want bind for each data json row.